# PHP Copy: no such file or directory

Tags: php, copy

Firstly: I **have** searched this, but all the answers seem to be either 'are you sure the path exists?' or 'has the path got the right permissions?' - I am 100% certain they do, not least because a different part of the code *in the same file* manages to write fine to the specified directory.

So: why is this extraordinarily simple bit of PHP not working properly?

`copy("/var/www/html/log16-1/0049_2016_07_27_08_00_08.mp3", "~/temp/xra231y.mp3");`

Results in the error:

`copy(~/temp/xra231y.mp3): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

I repeat: the path does exist, it does have the correct write permissions (this script is loaded from the CLI) and another part of the code in the same file manages to write to this directory with no issues at all (apart from speed, but then again it's joining MP3 files together!).

I've even tried using different quotation marks (I tend to use single rather than double usually) as I know they're slightly different things if that was going to make an issue, but to no avail.

Comment: shouldn't you use http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php ?

Comment: I'm not uploading a file. I am trying to copy a file that has been made by another process into the ~/temp/ folder where I can then, using a batch operation when there're enough files in there, upload them to somewhere on the interwebs. Those two parts of the code is working, it's just the middle part that isn't!

Comment: Show the code you use when it does work for this file.

Comment: Show us code or look for knife, incense, chicken and a bucket.

Comment: @RST: Problem now solved; the working code used ``exec(...)`` to copy the file (as it was also joining several files at once) which is why it worked.

Comment: @tereško: The code I gave was the sole code that was not working, except that I had cut out the bits where the filenames were given to the code as they weren't relevant, and the code wasn't working with or without that bit. Despite this being my 'first' post, I do know how SO works, and had a longer-term account which I've since lost both the password and the password to the email address of!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with /home//temp/xra231y.mp3, because  php doesn't expand the '~' in path automatically. If you need to have the tilde expanded for a generic user use something like this:

```
function expand_tilde($path)
{
    if (function_exists('posix_getuid') && strpos($path, '~') !== false) {
        $info = posix_getpwuid(posix_getuid());
        $path = str_replace('~', $info['dir'], $path);
    }

    return $path;
}
```

([source](http://jonathonhill.net/2013-09-03/tilde-expansion-in-php/))

Comment: That did it. Didn't realise that PHP didn't use the ~ path. (The other code was done in ``exec(...)`` which would be why that did work. Amusingly, I only used ~/temp as it seemed a convenient place to put it! Have changed it now to the main home path and will alter it - as planned anyway - before code goes into production. Thank you!